# display number on iphone icon

Tags: iphone

I want to display numbers on icon of iphone application

Please see reference file.
http://c.upanh.com/upload/7/291/VK0.11503211_1_1.jpg

how can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You gotta set the application badge number...here is a reference [UIAPplication ref](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationIconBadgeNumber)